# Magento 2 custom shipping charges based on Category

Tags: magento2.3.2

i was facing hard-time while creating a custom shipping charges.there is a demand that the shipping charges will be based on categories I.E different shipping charges applicable for different categories  product.

till now i have not found any luck on this. is there anyone who have already tried that and has some knowledge regarding this will be a great help thank you!

Comment: What you  have tried So far

Comment: i was not getting any idea how to deal with this..as i have never faced any such problem yet

Comment: This custom shipping method right?

Comment: custom shipping method and the calculation should be based on the basis of category

Comment: Hello , I have an idea about this thing if you want then I develope a custom extension for you.

Comment: okay how long will it take

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this thing using Plugin.

You can create `di.xml` file in your custom module here

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml

Content for this file is..

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Shipping\Model\CarrierFactory">
        <plugin name="custom_condition_in_shipping_methods" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Model\CarrierFactory" sortOrder="10"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

Now you need to create one `Plugin` file here in your custom module

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Plugin/Model/CarrierFactory.php

Content for this file is..

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Model;

class CarrierFactory
{
    protected $_scopeConfig;

    protected $_objectManager;

    protected $_checkoutSession;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $_checkoutSession
    ) {
        $this->_scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->_objectManager = $objectManager;
        $this->_checkoutSession = $_checkoutSession;
    }

    public function aroundGet(
        \Magento\Shipping\Model\CarrierFactory $subject,
        $Closure,
        $carrierCode
    ) {
        /*Change your logic here based on your requirement.*/
        $grandTotal = $this->_checkoutSession->getQuote()->getGrandTotal();
        if($grandTotal > 99 && $carrierCode != 'freeshipping'){
            return false;
        }
        /*Change your logic here based on your requirement.*/

        $className = $this->_scopeConfig->getValue(
            'carriers/' . $carrierCode . '/model',
            \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
        );
        if (!$className) {
            return false;
        }
        $carrier = $this->_objectManager->get($className);
        $carrier->setId($carrierCode);
        return $carrier;
    }

    public function aroundCreate(
        \Magento\Shipping\Model\CarrierFactory $subject,
        $Closure,
        $carrierCode,
        $storeId = null
    ) {
        /*Change your logic here based on your requirement.*/
        $grandTotal = $this->_checkoutSession->getQuote()->getGrandTotal();
        if($grandTotal > 99 && $carrierCode != 'freeshipping'){
            return false;
        }
        /*Change your logic here based on your requirement.*/

        $className = $this->_scopeConfig->getValue(
            'carriers/' . $carrierCode . '/model',
            \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
            $storeId
        );
        if (!$className) {
            return false;
        }
        $carrier = $this->_objectManager->create($className);
        $carrier->setId($carrierCode);
        if ($storeId) {
            $carrier->setStore($storeId);
        }
        return $carrier;
    }
}
```

You can change your logic in **Plugin** based on your requirements, this will work when order's grand total is more than 99 then it will only display **FREE SHIPPING** and if order total is below 99 then it will display all other shipping methods and not display FREE SHIPPING there.

> Note : You can change your logic in `aroundCreate()` and `aroundGet()` functions as per your requirements.

Hope this will help you!

Comment: ok means i have to get my category class here ryt

Comment: Yes, you can check Product's category in that functions and based on your requirement you can add conditions there.

Comment: Let me know if you still need any help here then. :)

Comment: its not working after implementing this...i get an error unable to save at the time of shipping

Comment: What is your magento version ?

Comment: lattest one that is magento 2.3.3

Comment: Okay then after adding this code did you run all deployment commands ?

Comment: yep compile, upgrade and deployed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101547/discussion-between-kishan-savaliya-and-pramod).

Comment: i need one favour from you

Comment: @Pramod, Yes let me know

Comment: actually i have a query check this out https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/298598/inventory-management-based-on-customer-group

Comment: You need to do so many customization for it, I think in default Magento is not providing such feature.

Comment: yes lets discuss this thing. i dnt think many people have tried this things so far

Answer (score 0):

**First, create your Custom Shipping method using this article** https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/howdoi/checkout/checkout-add-custom-carrier.html

After that, you need to customization on `public function collectRates(RateRequest $request)`  so, set **Shipping rate** as per your logic.

At this method, from `$request` you can current quote items `$request->getAllItems()` and  from the item you can get product id   and Sku

### Sample code

```
<?php

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

namespace Magento\OfflineShipping\Model\Carrier\Flatrate;

use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest;
use Magento\Shipping\Model\Carrier\AbstractCarrier;
use Magento\Shipping\Model\Carrier\CarrierInterface;

/**
 * Custom shipping model
 */
class Customshipping extends AbstractCarrier implements CarrierInterface
{

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface
     */
    private $productRepository;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface
     */
    private $categoryRepository;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_code = 'customshipping';

    /**
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $_isFixed = true;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\ResultFactory
     */
    private $rateResultFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\MethodFactory
     */
    private $rateMethodFactory;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\ErrorFactory $rateErrorFactory
     * @param \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
     * @param \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\ResultFactory $rateResultFactory
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\MethodFactory $rateMethodFactory
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\ErrorFactory $rateErrorFactory,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\ResultFactory $rateResultFactory,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\MethodFactory $rateMethodFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository,  
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($scopeConfig, $rateErrorFactory, $logger, $data);

        $this->rateResultFactory = $rateResultFactory;
        $this->rateMethodFactory = $rateMethodFactory;
        $this->categoryRepository = $categoryRepository;
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
    }

    /**
     * Custom Shipping Rates Collector
     *
     * @param RateRequest $request
     * @return \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\Result|bool
     */
    public function collectRates(RateRequest $request)
    {
        if (!$this->getConfigFlag('active')) {
            return false;
        }

        $productIds = [];
        $skus = [];

        foreach ($request->getAllItems() as $item) {

            /** Avoid Child Product **/
            if ($item->getProduct()->isVirtual() || $item->getParentItem()) {
                continue;
            }
            $productIds[] = $item->getProductId();
            $skus[] = $item->getSku();

        }
        $storeId = $request->getStoreId();
        /**
         * Test with Static Sku and can remove
         */
        $shippingCost = 0;

        $anSku = 'test001';
        $fullProductLoad = $this->getFullProductLoad($storeId, $sku);
        if ($fullProductLoad) {

            if ($categoryIds = $product->getCustomAttribute('category_ids')) {
                foreach ($categoryIds->getValue() as $categoryId) {
                    if($categoryId == 'MYCategorYId'){
                        $shippingCost = 150;
                    }
                    //$category = $this->categoryRepository->get($categoryId);
                }
            }
        }




        /** @var \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\Result $result */
        $result = $this->rateResultFactory->create();

        /** @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\Method $method */
        $method = $this->rateMethodFactory->create();

        $method->setCarrier($this->_code);
        $method->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('title'));

        $method->setMethod($this->_code);
        $method->setMethodTitle($this->getConfigData('name'));

        $shippingCost = (float)$this->getConfigData('shipping_cost');

        $method->setPrice($shippingCost);
        $method->setCost($shippingCost);

        $result->append($method);

        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getAllowedMethods()
    {
        return [$this->_code => $this->getConfigData('name')];
    }

    private function getFullProductLoad($storeId,$sku)
    {
        try{
             $product = $this->productRepository->get($sku, false, $storeId);
             return $product;
        } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException $ex) {

        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: wait i will give it a try

Comment: Please note that the code is not full build for your code. But the  parameters or variable need to your requirement is available

Comment: then how can i get category id here??

Comment: Please check Answer properly

Comment: `$item->getProductId() & $item->getSku() ` provide product id & sku repectively and  also see `getFullProductLoad()`